# Desactivar un checkbox al elegir una de las opciones

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Hola quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de dejar fijo al dar clic una de las dos opciones del checkbox y deshabilitar la otra opción no elegida, solo logro desactivar el checkbox elegido utilizando e.target.disabled = true en una función.

```
 <span>Si 
     <input value={objeto} type="checkbox" onChange={(e) =>  {setName(e.target.value);}} onInput={save} placeholder="Name" /> 
     </span>
      
  <span>No
     <input value={item} type="checkbox" onInput={save} placeholder="Name"  /> 
     </span>
```

Comment: La forma más facil es usar botones de radio, pues para eso estan, para autoexcluirse. O sea, `type="radio"` en lugar de `type="checkbox"` (eso sí debes agregar un atributo `name=` identico en ambos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más facil es usar botones de radio, pues para eso estan, para autoexcluirse. O sea, `type="radio"` en lugar de `type="checkbox"`.

Eso sí, debes agregar un atributo **name=** idéntico en ambos.

Ejemplo:

```html
<span>Si 
     <input name="botonRadio" value={objeto} type="radio" onChange={(e) =>  {setName(e.target.value);}} onInput={save} placeholder="Name" /> 
</span>

<span>No
     <input name="botonRadio" value={item} type="radio" onInput={save} placeholder="Name"  /> 
</span>
```

Tal como has indicado en el comentario, si lo que quieres es deshabilitar el otro checkbox y que no haya vuelta atrás puedes hacerlo del siguiente modo:

```js
function deshabilitarCasilla(el) {
  casillas = document.querySelectorAll('.casilla')
  casillas.forEach(x => x.disabled = "disabled");
  // Si quieres que siga activo el seleccionado descomenta la siguiente línea
  // el.disabled=''
}
```

```html
<span>Si
  <input class="casilla" onclick="deshabilitarCasilla(this)" value={objeto} type="checkbox" />
</span>

<span>No
  <input class="casilla" onclick="deshabilitarCasilla(this)" value={item} type="checkbox" placeholder="Name" />
</span>
```

Así seria con botones de radio, dejándo el seleccionado sin deshabilitar (porque si esta disabled luego no se envia en un formulario, si es que lo tienes dentro de uno).

```js
function deshabilitarCasilla(el) {
  radioBotones = document.querySelectorAll('.radioBoton')
  radioBotones.forEach(x => x.disabled = "disabled");
  el.disabled = ''
}
```

```html
<span>Si 
     <input class="radioBoton" onclick="deshabilitarCasilla(this)" name="botonRadio" value={objeto} type="radio"  placeholder="Name" /> 
</span>

<span>No
     <input class="radioBoton" onclick="deshabilitarCasilla(this)" name="botonRadio" value={item} type="radio" placeholder="Name"  /> 
</span>
```

Comment: Pero lo que quiero lograr es supongamos que elegí el Si, que ya no se pueda modificar ni poder dar click en No

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta, pero no se si te servirá, ya comentas lo que falte.

Comment: Y acabo de agregar una última opción que me parece más indicada, con botones de radio, pues dejo el boton de radio activo y podrá ser enviado en un formulario normal, y al deshabilitar el otro ya no se puede quitar la selección.